# Windows 8 WWW porting issue

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, porting

Trying to port a game, I'm having trouble making a high score board for a unity app for the windows 8 app store. The issue is that it never returns the results. I ran fiddler and can't see the game generating any packets.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;

public class Highscore : MonoBehaviour 
{
public string secretKey = "12345";
public string PostScoreUrl = "http://YouWebsite.com/.../postScore.php?";
public string GetHighscoreUrl = "http://YouWebsite.com/.../getHighscore.php";

private string name = "Name";
private string score = "Score";
private string WindowTitel = "";
private string Score = "";

public GUISkin Skin;
public float windowWidth = 400;
private float windowHeight = 250;
public Rect windowRect;

public int maxNameLength = 10;
public int getLimitScore = 15;


void Start () 
{
windowRect = new Rect (120, 40, 300, 300);
StartCoroutine("GetScore"); 
}

void Update () 
{
windowRect = new Rect (Screen.width / 3 , Screen.width / 6,Screen.width / 3,Screen.width / 3);
windowHeight = Screen.height - 50;
}

IEnumerator GetScore()
{
Score = "";

WindowTitel = "Loading";

WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("limit",getLimitScore);

WWW www = new WWW(GetHighscoreUrl,form);
yield return www;

if(www.text == "") 
{
print("There was an error getting the high score: " + www.error);
WindowTitel = "There was an error getting the high score";
}
else 
{
WindowTitel = "Highscore Board";
Debug.Log (www);
Score = www.text;
}
}

IEnumerator PostScore(string name, int score)
{
string _name = name;
int _score = score;

if (_name != "Name"){

string hash = Md5Sum(_name + _score + secretKey).ToLower();

WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("name",_name);
form.AddField("score",_score);
form.AddField("hash",hash);

WWW www = new WWW(PostScoreUrl,form);
WindowTitel = "Wait";
yield return www;

if(www.text == "done") 
{
StartCoroutine("GetScore");
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("currentScore", 0);
}
else 
{
print("There was an error posting the high score: " + www.error);
WindowTitel = "There was an error posting the high score";
}
} else { WindowTitel = "Enter your name before posting a high score"; }
}

void OnGUI()
{
GUI.skin = Skin;

windowRect = GUI.Window(0, windowRect, DoMyWindow, WindowTitel);

name = GUI.TextField (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - Screen.height / 10 - Screen.height / 5, Screen.height / 3 - Screen.height / 7, Screen.height / 5, Screen.height / 15), name, maxNameLength);
score = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("currentScore").ToString();

if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - Screen.width / 30 + Screen.width / 20, Screen.height / 3 - Screen.height / 7, Screen.height / 5 + 50, Screen.height / 15),"Post Score"))
{
StartCoroutine(PostScore(name, int.Parse(score)));
name = "";
score = "";
} 
}

void DoMyWindow(int windowID) 
{
GUI.skin = Skin;

GUI.Label (new Rect (windowWidth / 2 + windowWidth / 15 + windowWidth / 15 + windowWidth / 25, windowHeight / 15 , windowWidth, windowHeight), Score);


}

public string Md5Sum(string input)
{
byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
byte[] hash = UnityEngine.Windows.Crypto.ComputeMD5Hash(inputBytes);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
{
sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
}
return sb.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: The relevant portions of your code need to be in your question here. Please edit to include that code (only the relevant portions). We shouldn't have to go somewhere else to figure out what you're asking. While you're at it, please edit the subject so that you're not SHOUTING AT US. It's not polite (and it makes your question harder to read), and it won't get you help any faster typing it that way. Thanks

Comment: Nobody will wade through that pile of unformatted code you posted on pastebin. If you like to have an answer to your question, please take the time to write a good question (read [this](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)).